# Pyspark writing data into hive

Tags: python, shell, hadoop, apache-spark

Below is my code to write data into Hive

```
from pyspark import since,SparkContext as sc
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import _functions , isnan
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark import HiveContext as hc


spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("example-spark").config("spark.sql.crossJoin.enabled","true").config('spark.sql.warehouse.dir',"file:///C:/spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7/bin/metastore_db/spark-warehouse").config('spark.rpc.message.maxSize','1536').getOrCreate()
Name= spark.read.csv("file:///D:/valid.csv", header="true",inferSchema = 
True,sep=',')

join_df=join_df.where("LastName != ''").show()  
join_df.registerTempTable("test")
hc.sql("CREATE TABLE dev_party_tgt_repl STORED AS PARQUETFILE AS SELECT * from dev_party_tgt")
```

After executing the above code I get below error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\01 Delivery Support\01 
easyJet\SparkEclipseWorkspace\SparkTestPrograms\src\NameValidation.py", line 
22, in <module>
join_df.registerTempTable("test")
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'test'
```

My System Environment details:

- OS:Windows
- Eclipse Neon
- Spark Version :2.0.0

Comment: I think you should remove the `.show()` at the end of `join_df=join_df.where("LastName != ''").show()`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
join_df.where("LastName != ''").write.saveAsTable("dev_party_tgt_repl")
```

Comment: Thank you Piotr for the answer. When I am using the .saveAsTable . I am getting error as given below
join_df=join_df.where("LastName != ''").saveAsTable()
  File "E:\spark-2.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7\spark-2.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\sql\dataframe.py", line 973, in __getattr__
    "'%s' object has no attribute '%s'" % (self.__class__.__name__, name))
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'saveAsTable'

Comment: Hi @NaveenSrikanth , I've forgot to add `write`. I've changed answer, please try again.